# Function that returns a pointer always returns the same value

Tags: c++, pointers, return-value, calloc

I am fairly new to C++ programming and I have trouble understanding where I'm going wrong with my current project. I have a large array of uint32_t that I want to fill with preprocessed values. All is fine for the first computation, but starting from the second one only the memory address of the *processed pointer changes, not its value.

```
uint32_t *candPreprocessed = (uint32_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * indices.size());
for(int j = 0; j < indices.size()-1; j++)
{
    char *candidate = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (indices[j+1] - indices[j]) + 1);

    ... 

    uint32_t *processed = preprocess((uint8_t*) candidate, len);
    memcpy(candPreprocessed + j * sizeof(uint32_t), processed, sizeof(uint32_t));
    processed = NULL;

    // free the messages
    free(candidate);
    free(processed);
}
```

The preprocessing looks like this:

```
uint32_t* preprocess(uint8_t *word, size_t wordLength)
{
    uint8_t *toProcess = (uint8_t*) calloc(120, 1);

     ...

    return (uint32_t*) (toProcess);
}
```

In my understanding, the free(processed) call should free the memory occupied by the pointer created during the preprocessing. In the following iteration of the loop a new candidate is fetched and a new length gets computed, so the arguments change. What am I missing, why isn't this reflected in the output?

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
As requested, the short self contained compiling example -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

uint32_t* preprocess(uint8_t *word, size_t wordLength)
{
    // preprocessing
    uint8_t *toProcess = (uint8_t*) calloc(120, 1);
    memcpy(toProcess, word, wordLength);
    toProcess[wordLength] = 128;
    int numBits = 8 * wordLength;
    memcpy(toProcess + 56, &numBits, 1);
    return (uint32_t*) (toProcess);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char cand[12] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c'};
int indices[4] = {0,4,8,12};
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    // extract the message from the wordlist
    char *candidate = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (4) + 1);
    int i=0;
    for(int k = indices[j]; k < indices[j+1]; k++)
        candidate[i++] = cand[k];
    candidate[i] = '\0';
    size_t len = strlen(candidate);

    uint32_t *processed = preprocess((uint8_t*) candidate, len);

    std::cout << processed << std::endl;

    // free the messages
    free(candidate);
    free(processed);
}

return 0;
}
```

This produces three outputs, two of which are the same.

Comment: Which arguments change?

Comment: Also can you give some example input and output and describe how it differs from what you expect?

Comment: "word" is extracted from a char array in every iteration, "wordLength" denotes the length of the extracted message. Both change in every iteration of the loop and every consecutive call of preprocess(). EDIT: Sure. For example, the input "aaaa" with length 4 generates the output "12345". Now, the second time around, "bbb" with length 3 also generates "12345".

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger to check that `word` and `wordLength` contain the expected values on each call.

Comment: Yes I have, they have the expeted values.

Comment: How does your program transform the input "aaaa" into the output "12345"?

Comment: `memcpy(toProcess, word, wordLength);
toProcess[wordLength] = 128;
int numBits = 8 * wordLength;
memcpy(toProcess + 56, &numBits, 1);`

Comment: `processed = NULL;` followed by `free(processed);` can't be right?

Comment: Your code is neither complete, nor simple.  Can you provide actual code that actually compiles and demonstrates your problem?  And make it short: remove stuff that you don't think will be needed to demonstrate your problem, recompile and test that the problem still occurs, and repeat until you have a [Short Self Contained Compiling Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: And did you step through *that* code to make sure it processes the input c-string as expected for both examples?

Comment: Slight change in meaning: `should free the memory occupied by the pointer` Not quite. I would say `should free the memory pointed at by a pointer`. Note: this does not mean the values in this piece of memory. The memory sub-system can then re-use the memory on a subsequent request.

Comment: Do you really need all those `malloc` calls?  Can you use automatic or stack variables instead?  Also, try using `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Simplify your life and use `std::vector`.  You can pass it by reference or constant reference.  The `std::vector` is like an array than can adjust itself automatically.

Comment: As I mentioned I am fairly new to C(++) and never had to worry about such a huge amount of memory management before. @Daniel Earwicker `processed = NULL` is something I added later on when I tried to solve the problem, it is not causing it @Yakk I will try @Thomas Matthews I will try to refactor it

Answer (score 0):

This line appears to be appending the results from one iteration to a larger buffer:

```
 memcpy(candPreprocessed + j * sizeof(uint32_t), processed, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

But it only copies 4 bytes (a single `uint32_t`). That might be the problem.

If it *is* the problem, and you fix it, then the next problem would be that the destination buffer isn't big enough to take all the results.

You mention C++ programming - you will find this a whole lot easier if you try actually using C++! `std::vector` will help a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use std::vector in this case because the result of the above is directly fed into an OpenCL kernel which only supports C-style arrays

Comment: If you have a `std::vector<T> v` you can say `&v[0]` to get a pointer to the first item, which is guaranteed (by the standard) to be followed contiguously in memory by all the other items. So just say `&v[0]` to "convert" to a C-style array. And use `v.size()` to get the number of items (NB. NOT the number of bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Since the description of the problem is pretty vague still (despite LOTS of comments), I'm having a bit of a guess:

```
memcpy(candPreprocessed + j * sizeof(uint32_t), processed, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

looks wrong to me. `candPreprocessed` is a pointer to `uint32_t`. I suspect you don't actually want to move data into the `candPreprocessed` array at every 4 entries.

Try:

```
memcpy(candPreprocessed + j, processed, sizeof(uint32_t));
```